# Smooth Scrolling Script broken with newer version of jQuery

Tags: jquery, scroll, easing

I have this very simple script for easing the mousewheel scrolling on my website. It works great with jQuery 1.8.3, but not at all with 2.0.1 which is what I already have on my website for another script. I was wondering what could be the cause of this script not working on a newer version of jQuery?

[FIDDLE WIT IT](http://jsfiddle.net/6G32P/339/)

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.easing, {
    easeOutQuint: function(x, t, b, c, d) {
        return c * ((t = t / d - 1) * t * t * t * t + 1) + b;
    }
});

var wheel = false,
    $docH = $(document).height() - $(window).height(),
    $scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
    if (wheel === false) {
        $scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    }
});
$(document).bind('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel', function(e, delta) {
    delta = delta || -e.originalEvent.detail / 3 || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 120;
    wheel = true;

    $scrollTop = Math.min($docH, Math.max(0, parseInt($scrollTop - delta * 30)));
    $($.browser.webkit ? 'body' : 'html').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $scrollTop + 'px'
    }, 500, 'easeOutQuint', function() {
        wheel = false;
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's this line

```
$($.browser.webkit ? 'body' : 'html').stop().animate({ ...
```

jQuery's `$.browser` was deprecated as early as jQuery 1.3, and finally removed in jQuery 1.9

You can just do this instead

```
$('body, html').stop().animate({ ....
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6G32P/344/)